# Django get value from db before form.save()

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to create an application where I can save timestamps for users. Now, my form works right now but I need to make sure the mpr_id exists in Player table before form.save() How could I make my application do that?

If mpr_id doesn't exist in Player show error in form

this is my forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import PlayerRecordTime

class AddTimeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PlayerRecordTime
        fields = ['mpr_id']
```

models.py:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    mpr_id = models.CharField(verbose_name="MPR ID", max_length=3,     editable=True, unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Nombre Completo", max_length=200, editable=True)
    phone = models.CharField(verbose_name="Telefono", max_length=10, editable=True)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="Email", editable=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Jugador"
    verbose_name_plural = "Jugadores"
    ordering = ['mpr_id']

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.mpr_id


class CheckPoint(models.Model):
id = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="ID", unique=True, editable=False, primary_key=True)
place_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Nombre Lugar", max_length=60, editable=True, default=True, unique=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "CheckPoint"
    verbose_name_plural = "CheckPoints"

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.place_name


class PlayerRecordTime(models.Model):
mpr_id = models.CharField(verbose_name="MPRID", max_length="3", editable=True)
place_name_id = models.CharField(verbose_name="Check Point ID", max_length=1)
check_in_time = models.TimeField(verbose_name="CheckIn Time", auto_now=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Tiempo"
    verbose_name_plural = "Tiempos"
    unique_together = ('mpr_id', 'place_name_id')

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.mpr_id
```

views.py

```
def cp(request, cpid, template_name):
title = "ScavengerRun - CP%s" % cpid
head = "Check Point %s" % cpid

form = AddTimeForm()

if request.method == "POST":
    form = AddTimeForm(request.POST)
    form.instance.place_name_id = cpid
    if form.is_valid():
        try:
            form.save()
            form = AddTimeForm()
        except IntegrityError:
            form.errors["mpr_id"] = ["Ya existe un record"]
    else:
        pass

context = {
    "title": title,
    "head": head,
    "form": form,
    "cpid": cpid
}
return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Will appreciate the help.

Comment: AddTimeForm is modelform for PlayerRecordTime. Do you need check if mpr_id form value also exists in Player records ? If that so why there is no relation between Player and PlayerRecordTime ?

Comment: @JoanBlackmoore because I clearly forgot to mention that I'm not so expert with django and when I tried to make a relation between Player and PlayerRecordTime in the models.py, my form produce a dropdown with the list fo mpr_id's and I don't want that, I need a TextInput in the form.

Comment: Uh, it may be the part of the issue. You should really read Django docs about available model relations and define one. This would fix fields duplicities incl. mpr_id. If the mpr_id is of type CharField and used in form for model which defines it, it would be represented with text input field by default, like you request.

Comment: @JoanBlackmoore thank you for the super idea to read the same documentations I'm reading for few days prior asking this question here. Anyways, it was very easy to give me some pointer to what I need to search there and I can take care of the rest, instead of pointing at loud my lack of knowledge with Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if object exists by get() function

```
if request.method == "POST":
form = AddTimeForm(request.POST)
form.instance.place_name_id = cpid
if form.is_valid():
    try:
        plyr = Players.objects.get(mpr_id == form.cleaned_data["mpr_id"])
        form.save()
        form = AddTimeForm()
    except IntegrityError:
        form.errors["mpr_id"] = ["Ya existe un record"]
    except DoesNotExist:
        //does not save
else:
    pass
```

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it.

Comment: Oh my bad should have explain it better. Ok you use Players.object.get function to get the object mpr_id of form from database if it is not on database function raises DoesNotExist exception in except part you dont save form to database because you said you dont want it. If it does not raise the exception you save form to database

Comment: thank you, with what you said it gives me a little light.

Comment: Np man i would really appreciate if you would accept my answer

Comment: Well I had to: from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist and change the except to: except (ValueError, ObjectDoesNotExist): now is giving me the Value does not exist but it also does when the value is actually true and exist in db.

Comment: Can you post the full exception and tell me when it happens